# Deadlock on query that is executed simultaneously

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've got a stored procedure that does the following (Simplified):

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

DECLARE @intNo int
SET @intNo = (SELECT MAX(intNo) + 1 FROM tbl)
INSERT INTO tbl(intNo)
Values (@intNo)

SELECT intNo  
      FROM tbl
      WHERE (intBatchNumber = @intNo - 1)  

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

My issue is that when two or more users execute this at the same time I am getting deadlocks. Now as I understand it the moment I do my first select in the proc this should create a lock in tbl. If the second procedure is then called while the first procedure is still executing it should wait for it to complete right?

At the moment this is causing a deadlock, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `insert` query requires a different lock than the `select`.  The lock for `select` blocks a second `insert`, but it does not block a second `select`.  So both queries can start with the `select`, but they both block on the other's `insert`.

You can solve this by asking the first query to lock the entire table:

```
SET @intNo = (SELECT MAX(intNo) + 1 FROM tbl with (tablockx))
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This will make the second transaction's `select` wait for the complete first transaction to finish.

Comment: Can this problem be solved by changing the ISOLATION LEVEL to SERIALIZABLE?

Answer (score 1):

Make it simpler so you have one statement and no transaction

```
--BEGIN TRANSACTION  not needed

INSERT INTO tbl(intNo)
OUTPUT INSERTED.intNo
SELECT MAX(intNo) + 1 FROM tbl WITH (TABLOCK)

--COMMIT TRANSACTION not needed
```

Although, why aren't you using IDENTITY...?

Comment: Unfortunately this database comes from 2000 and we still have some legacy apps in place so I can't change it to an identity field